# Choose whether or not to store sent sms messages in inbox

Tags: android, sms, sharedpreferences, smsmanager

I have an app where the user can input a phone number, and a message and can click "send" and it will send the message to the phone number they set it to. When the user sends the message, that specific message also appears in their messaging inbox on their phone. What I am trying to accomplish, is making a checkbox preference where the user can check or uncheck whether or not the messages they send will be saved to their messaging inbox.

Here is my checkbox preference in prefs.xml

```
<CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key_addvalues"
            android:summary="Choose whether to store sent messages in your inbox"
            android:title="Store messages"
            android:defaultValue="true"
        />
```

Here is main.xml

```
public class EasyTextActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String userTheme = prefs.getString("key_theme", "dark");

            if (userTheme.equals("dark"))
                setTheme(R.style.HoloTheme);
            else if (userTheme.equals("light"))
                setTheme(R.style.HoloLight);
            else if (userTheme.equals("lightdark"))
                setTheme(R.style.HoloLightDark);

            String addvalues = prefs.getString("key_addvalues", "on");


            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);  
            registerForContextMenu(btn);  

            buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
            textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
            textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

            buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                  String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                  String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
                  try {               
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                       
                    values.put("address", phoneNo);                               
                    values.put("body", sms);                              
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Unable to send message",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                }
            }); 
        }
```

As you can see, I successfully added a preference where the user can select a theme from a list, however I cannot seem to figure out how to add the preference where they can choose whether or not the messages save to their inbox.

In order to have the messages save to their inbox, I added this code when the message sends:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                       
                    values.put("address", phoneNo);                               
                    values.put("body", sms);                              
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

However I am clueless on how exactly I am suppose to make the above code into a preference. Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`CheckBoxPreference` saves a boolean value and not a `on/off` string.
In your case to retrieve the value it would enough to call:

```
final boolean save = prefs.getBoolean("key_addvalues", true);
```

And then check the `save`variable:

```
if(save){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                       
    values.put("address", phoneNo);                               
    values.put("body", sms);                              
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to place `final boolean save = prefs.getBoolean("key_addvalues", true);` Because no matter where I place the app I get a runtime error. The `if(save){` doesn't seem to matter whether it is in the code or not, it is the final boolean that is causing the crash. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?? I'm really lost here